# Finding the Sum of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm given this:

$3+12+48+...+3072$

I know the first term is 3, the last is 3072, I don't know the amount of terms.
I'm told to use sigma notation to solve it, but I have no idea how to find the general term here, because I can't use a calculator:
If i use the equation for the general term, I would need a calculator to solve it.

I know the common ratio is 4 here, but not sure how to go about doing this.
Btw I'm told to start at $n =1 , $ not $n = 0$

Comment: The sequence is $3(1+4+4^2+4^3+4^4+4^5)$.  Aside from the $3$, that's just the first few terms of a geometric series.  Can you compute that?

Comment: @lulu Even including the $3$, that's still a geometric series with the same common ratio (but a different first term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the ratio of two consecutive terms of the given series is constant hence the given series is a G.P. having first term $a=3$, & a common ratio $r=4$

Let $n$ be the number of terms of the given series then the last $n$th  term is $3072$ which is given bythe general formula as follows

$$T_n=ar^{n-1}$$ $$3(4)^{n-1}=3072$$
$$(2^2)^{n-1}=\frac{3072}{3}=1024$$
$$(2)^{2n-2}=2^{10}$$
Comparing the powers both the sides we get 
$$2n-2=10\implies n=6$$ 
Hence, there are total $n=6$ terms in the given G.P.

Answer (score 0):

Each term is $3 \times 4^i$ for $i = 0, ..., 5$.